# Dialog box not opening when including a header file

Tags: visual-c++

I have made an server application. It is mfc dialog based application. Dialog has option for starting server in listen mode. When client connects to server it shows packets it has send and packet it has received. I have made seperate CSockServer class which is derived from CAsyncSocket class. This thing is working all right.

Now I want a serializable class that gets the device information to which i want to connect which is stored in a file. This file is created by another dialog application. Same devinfo class that I had made in that application i Have made in this server application . When i am including header file of this DevInfo class in ServerDialog.cpp class. Server project is compiling but dialog box is not appearing at all.

When i am running this program in debugging mode Unhandled exception error is appearing in this line of CDeviceServerv1.cpp class

```
m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
```

Please Help 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Set a breackpoint in that line and watch the value of this. I bet it is NULL or some garbage value. The function was probably called too soon through a pointer that was not yet pointing to an object.

Comment: Oh, and see also the "call stack" window. It will tell you which line of code called the current function. Just double-click in the different lines of the call stack to see the caller line in every level.

Comment: I have find out that cause for not appearing main dialog is not inclusion of header file but declaration of following line:   CObArray m_oaDevInfo;   When I am declaring this line in header file of ServerDialog.h file it is not showing up dialog. But when I am commenting it out dialog is appearing on executing

Comment: Was that declaration at global scope (not inside any class)? Cause that would be wrong in several ways. If you solved the problem, please post an answer and accept it.